# How to List Pages in Current Section

Tags: hugo

I'm trying to list the pages in the current url section.

- Get All Sections
- Limit range to current Section
- List pages in current Section

---

```
{{ range $value := .Site.Sections }}

    {{ range .Section }}

        {{ range $value.Pages }}
            <ul>
                <li>{{ .Title }}</li>
            </ul>
        {{ end }}

    {{ end }}

{{ end }}
```

Though it returns null because `{{ range .Section }}` is not valid code.

What is the correct way to do this?

https://gohugo.io/templates/variables/

Answer (score 11):

You need to filter `.Site.Pages` by section using the [`where` function](https://gohugo.io/functions/where/). Try this:

```
<ul>
{{ range where .Site.Pages "Section" .Section }}
  <li>{{ .Title }}</li>
{{ end }}
</ul>
```

If you want to avoid empty lists, you can store the slice of section pages in a variable and check its length before you output the ul tags.

```
{{ $sectionPages := where .Site.Pages "Section" .Section }}
{{ if ge (len $sectionPages) 1 }}
  <ul>
    {{ range $sectionPages }}
      <li>{{ .Title }}</li>
    {{ end }}
  </ul>
{{ end }}
```

Comment: Do you think you would be able to help with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46848467/hugo-error-calling-where-cant-evaluate-the-array-by-no-match-argument-or-more