# HUGO: error calling where: can't evaluate the array by no match argument or more than or equal to two arguments

Tags: hugo

I am trying to create a `ul` list of the sections of my hugo site and their child pages that have a specific param.

I basically want a multi-level ul menu at the side like so:

- Intro

  - Page 1
  - Page 2
- Section

  - page 3
  - page 4

Here is the Hugo Code I have so far:

```
<ul class="section-one-and-two-pages">
{{ range .Site.Pages }}
    {{ range where ( where .Section  "intro" ) or ".Params.type" "==" "article" }}
   <li>{{.Permalink}}{{.Title}}</li>
    {{end}}
{{ end }}
</ul>
```

At the top of my pages (.md) I am adding:

```
type: = "article"
```

However I cannot seem to get this to work. I keep getting the Error:

> Error calling where: can't evaluate the array by no match argument or more than or equal to two arguments

When compiling. Any ideas?

Comment: Is `type: = "article"` yaml or toml? To me it looks like a bit of both.

Comment: Not sure, I just coped the title: "Test Post" that was generated by hugo

Comment: Do you have any ideas on a solution to my problem? I'm literally pulling my hair our....

Comment: Could you post the whole of your .md file metadata, including the separators? I have a feeling that is where at least part of your problems is. Also, you should only need one "range" statement, but I'll need to actually test that before I can give you a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just for people running into this old question: the position of the 'or' is wrong. The right syntax is `or condition1 condition2`, see https://gohugo.io/functions/go-template/or/.

Read more about or and where at https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/using-or-with-where/10408.

Comment: please expand. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587. at least show the corrected version. ideally, explain why it's wrong.